# Зачем GraphQL если с сервера все равно загружаются все данные?

Tags: graphql

поскажите пожалуйста что касается GraphQL, начал активно его использовать, удобно все делается. Но такое чувство что использую его не до конца правильно

К примеру graphQL позиционируется как выборное селектирования данных из базы без надобности грузить все методы

Я к примеру испольузю apollo server ( express )и apollo client ( react )

Хочу получить только имя продукта

```
export const PRODUCT_BY_RESTAURANT = gql`
 query Products{
  Products){
   name
  }
 }
`
```

И мы получаем только имя

НО сам resolver выглядит таким обрзом

```
Products : async(parent, args) => {
      return await Product.find()
    },
```

Т.е мы ведь в любом случае загружаем с сервера все нужные нам данные....

Comment: Да, но на клиент отсылаются только нужные данные, а не все - экономим трафик :) И представьте, что вам надо на странице показать все продукты и еще что-то не связанное с ними, к примеру.  Обычно вы бы делали это двумя фетчами, а так все можно с одного запроса взять. Для маленких проектов, думаю разницы в удобстве не будет особо видно.

Comment: P.S. Можно просто писать: `Products: () => Product.find()` :) А еще лучше добавить какой-то отдельный слой - сервис к примеру, и писать что-то типа `Product: () => ProductService.getOne()`, чтобы когда будете что-то менять - пришлось менять в одном месте, а не везде.